# Помогите исправить ошибки

Tags: однокоренные-слова

1. Именно в это время появляются романтические произведения. в которых проявиласьмечта писателя о новом человеке. (Понятно, что "появляются" - "проявилась", но как одно из них заменить?)
2. Успех первых пьес значительно упрочил положение драматурга. (Какая здесь ошибка?)

Comment: > Именно в это время появляются
> романтические произведения. в которых
> проявиласьмечта писателя о новом
> человеке.

А кто автор этих самых *романтических произведений* — сам писатель или собрат по цеху? От этого выбор слова может зависеть. Для первого случая я бы избрал, например, слово отразить: "Именно в это время появляются романтические произведения, в которых
отразилась мечта писателя о новом человеке". *Воплотилась* (из ответа **Ларf**)— это что-то материализованное в большей мере (как *твёрдая копия*), чем изложенное. 

Comment: А вот что дает Ушаков: "Последний роман упрочил за ним славу талантливого писателя." 

Здесь всё понятно: слава была и от предыдущих романов, а теперь окрепла, заматерела. А в предложении задания — "успех первых пьес". Но если автор сам драматург по специальности, а не сложившийся прозаик, то до первых пьес кто о нём что знал? Так что "упрочил" здесь не к месту употреблено в смысле славы. Да и в материальном тоже.
Вот только в задании написано: "какие слова образованы неправильно?" Вроде образованы-то правильно...

Answer (score 10):

Произведения появляются - создаются. Мечта проявилась -  воплотилась. Чтобы изменить второе предложение, нужно знать, что Вы имеете в виду под словом положение... Может, материальное положение. Может, признание автора как драматурга. А потом уже править.

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу второго предложения - оно дано в учебнике без всякого контекста, в ряду остальных подобных предложений...

Comment: Я думаю просто "улучшил". "Упрочил положение" в любом случае - сомнительное сочетание.

Comment: Спасибо, согласна).

Comment: Задание в учебнике: какие слова образованы неправильно? Может, нельзя сказать "значительно упрочил"? И вот еще "С поразительной глубиной отражены в романе основные социальные противоречия эпохи".... "поразительная глубина"?

Comment: А вот что дает Ушаков:  "Последний роман упрочил за ним славу талантливого писателя." и "Сделать прочным, надежным, обеспеченным, укрепить. Упрочить свое положение"... Может, упрочил славу драматурга ( в нашем предложении)?

Comment: >"Сделать прочным, надежным, обеспеченным, укрепить. Упрочить свое положение"  
  
Боюсь, что тут можно объяснить иным смыслом. В порядке "имхо", ибо копать глубже сейчас не могу. Но если вопрос будет еще актуален - посмотрю внимательнее.

Answer (score 3):

Если это об упражнении 74,там задание: Укажите, какие ошибки допущены в употреблении однокоренных слов, какие слова образованы неправильно. Т.е.в каких-то неправильное словообразование, а в каких-то словоупотребление.

1.Именно в это время появляются романтические произведения, в которых  отразилась мечта писателя о новом человеке.

2.Успех первых пьес значительно укрепил положение драматурга.

С поразительной глубиной показаны(поразительной-отражены -однокоренные) в романе основные социальные противоречия эпохи"....